# Java RMI stand-alone applications

Tags: java, rmi

Java RMI stand-alone applications

Is it possible to create a Server – Client Java application using RMI that can run just by running the server and the client (with servers IP), without any change on any environment variable, or installation of any other program?

As far as I know, to make an RMI compo (Server – Client) to work, you need:
server application
client application
protocol file(s) (implementations) common for both

but the location of the server must be accessible by the client. Is there a way that java can make it accessible without any help?

Comment: Haven't used RMI before apparently Oracle says it comes with the Java Standard Edition. If I read your question right do you mean that the server has the RMI implemented but the client does not? I think this question is completely dependent on the specifics of what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: `"without any change on any environment variable, or installation of any other program?"` => What do you have to do now that requires any of this? What is the concrete step you want to avoid?

Comment: In the http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/java/tutorial/rmi/running.html for exaple says: "setenv CLASSPATH /home/ann/src:/home/ann/public_html/classes/compute.jar".
Wich means I need a classpath variable, and a web server "public_html".

Comment: @xbyte1024 Don't use ancient tutorials from third party sites. Have a look at the [*current version* from the *official source*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a Server – Client Java application using RMI that can run just by running the server and the client (with servers IP), without any change on any environment variable, or installation of any other program?

RMI doesn't have environment variables or separate programs.

> As far as I know, to make an RMI compo (Server – Client) to work, you need: server application client application protocol file(s) (implementations) common for both

No you don't. There is no such thing. You just need the relevant .class files in each place. I can't imagine where you are getting this misinformation from.

> but the location of the server must be accessible by the client. Is there a way that java can make it accessible without any help?

No. Accessibility is a property of firewalls. If you could change that from the client there wouldn't be any point in having them in the first place.